# MobX Observable map that stores observables maps

Tags: reactjs, observable, mobx

Is this the correct way to store multiple observable maps within a store.

I'm relatively new to working with observables and MobX. I have a store for any maintenance domain object. For example "Institution Types". Instead of using a map for each I initiate a new map based off of an enum created:

```
maintenanceRegistry = new Map<string, any>();
selectedMaintenanceList = new Map<string, any>();

constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this);
    Object.values(MaintenanceTypeEnum).forEach((value) => {
        this.maintenanceRegistry.set(value, new Map<string, any>());
      });
}
```

And then on my onClick I set the selectedMaintenance map using the enum as the key:

```
if (maintenanceRegistry.get(MaintenanceTypeEnum.InstitutionTypes).size <= 1) {
          loadMaintenance<InstitutionType>({apiPath: '/institutionTypes'});
        } else {
          setSelectedMaintenanceList(MaintenanceTypeEnum.StructureCategories);
        }
```

When I load the data it updates my table and values however when the data has already been fetched the table data is not being updated.

To fetch the data I am using a computed function:

```
get maintenanceValues() {
        var mv: any[] = [];
        [...this.selectedMaintenanceList.values()].map((value: {value: any}, i) => {
            mv.push(value);
            })
        return mv;
    }
```

and then I map the data without the id property as its a guid and unnecessary:

```
const data = (maintenanceValues).map(value => {
            const { id, ...noId } = value;
            return noId
        })
```